# galaxy s2 wont turn on just keeps popping up us cellular symbol than re does it again

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot-loop

My galaxy s2 charges normally but when I turn it on, it starts up and then just randomly keeps restarting. I have taken out the battery and it still does it. It also charges just fine when I just plug in my charger to my phone it shows up like it normally does with the battery and the dots under it. It was working just fine about 2 hours ago and now it wont load at all!

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you rooted? Using a custom ROM?

Comment: Which android version you are using? Are you using stock firmware or any custom ROM?

Comment: As you correctly tagged your question 'boot-loop': have you checked the [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info)? As many other tags, it contains some useful first-aid hints. You can reach those tag-wikis easily: hover your mouse over the tag, then select "info" in the pop-up. Or simply click/tapp the tag, and then select "Learn more..." (or simply the "info" tab).